# Incorrect results showing on Date conversion in php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
$testTime   =   strtotime("2016-03-03 07:40:45 pm");    
echo "final=".$final        =   DATE("Y-m-d H:i",$testTime);//2016-03-03 19:40
```

Showing the correct out put
But when ever I tried to change the hour to Zero

```
$testTime   =   strtotime("2016-03-03 00:30:45 am");    
echo "final=".$final        =   DATE("Y-m-d H:i",$testTime);//1970-01-01 01:00
```

Incorrect values are showing.
Any idea?

Comment: Either `00:30:45` or `12:30:45 am` would help.

Comment: the 24Hr clock doesn't use `am` or `pm`

Comment: You need to check first `$testTime` value is correct?

Comment: yes, remove `am/pm` or make it `12:30`, there is no 00:30 am

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using am/pm with 24 hours format. am/pm should be with 12 hr

**12 hour = 12:30:45 AM**

```
$testTime   =   strtotime("2016-03-03 12:30:45 am");
$final      =   DATE("Y-m-d H:i",$testTime);//1970-01-01 01:00
```

**24 hour = 00:30:45**

```
$testTime   =   strtotime("2016-03-03 00:30:45");
$final      =   DATE("Y-m-d H:i",$testTime);//1970-01-01 01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using am/pm with 24 hours format , Try this code

```
$testTime = strtotime("2016-03-03 12:30:45 am");    
echo "final=".$final = DATE("Y-m-d H:i",$testTime);
```