# php strtotime() off by 1 minute?

Tags: php, strtotime

Am i the only one who is getting this to return wrong time?

```
$date_str = "2016-Mar-28 06:04:31 PM";

$timestamp = strtotime($date_str);

echo date('Y-m-d H:m:s', $timestamp);'

//Returns: 2016-03-28 18:03:31
```

Note 18:**03**:31 not 18:**04**:31, my timezone is correct i bet it would be off by hours not 1 minute, running PHP 5.6.16

Comment: It's a problem with your format String.

Comment: m = month (march = 3).  i = minute with leading zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date_str = "2016-Mar-28 06:04:31 PM";

$timestamp = strtotime($date_str);

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

Answer:

```
2016-03-28 18:04:31
```

Issue: Wrong minute

```
  m = month
```

[Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125872/incorrect-results-showing-on-date-conversion-in-php/36126669#36126669)
[Ref 2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Ahhh i know i was missing something, i am was ready to blow my brains out because of this error, find out was just not careful